# Flip toggle switch jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I created a Flip toggle Switch with:

```
    <select id="flip1" data-role="flipswitch">
        <option value="true">true</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
    </select>
```

my script code looks like this:

```
    <script>
         $( "#flip1").change(function(){
              alert("flip");
         });
    </script>
```

but if I change the Button, nothing happened. Maybe someone can help me. Thank you

Comment: [Your code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/NG78a/1/).

Comment: Your code looks fine, make sure you have loaded `jQuery` library on your page

Comment: Is the dom ready? `$(document).ready(function() { // your code });`

Comment: make sure you have loaded jQuery library on your page

Comment: Here's the fiddle, including jQuery mobile http://jsfiddle.net/NG78a/2/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

with ready function

http://jsfiddle.net/z5stP/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#flip1").change(function(){
       alert("flip");
     });
   });  
</script>
```

Comment: thanks with this code it will work, i need to check how I loaded the jQuery library, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Open your Browser Console (F12) to see the errors on your Page.
Your code works but maybe your jQuery library could not found.

[https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers][1]

Answer (score -1):

```
try using below code

    <select id="flip1" data-role="flipswitch">
        <option value="true">true</option>
        <option value="false">false</option>
    </select>


<script>
$("document").ready(function()
{
     $( "#flip1").change(function(){
          alert("flip");
     });
});
</script>
```

Note: Always call ur script after dom is loaded. Enclosing user script inside $(document).ready() function ensures ur script to called after dom element is loaded